# Regex to combine multiple rows?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use a regex to combine multiple textrows?
For example row 1 with row 2, row 3 with row 4, etc, etc...
If I have rows like those:

```
s89j3hjd34nsd
j8324jdsfjfs
8hasdk3491es
hdf63hadsi9
```

Can I remove (replace with nothing) the ending of the row ($) for every two lines.
So it will result would be:

```
s89j3hjd34nsdj8324jdsfjfs
8hasdk3491eshdf63hadsi9
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do better. regex are used to search (and sometimes replace) text. "Combining" things doesn't sound like a good match. Also specify what language you're using, and some examples.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: The short answer is 'yes'. However, you give no indication as to which language you are interested or (more importantly) what you have tried thusfar and failed. As such, I vote to close as per [the site owner's advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94095/should-we-close-first-questions-when-they-are-of-poor-quality/94097#94097)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for

```
^(.*)\r?\n(.*)
```

and replace all with

```
$1$2
```

Be sure not to set the dot-matches-all mode, but do set the multiline mode of your regex engine.

Comment: Thanks! That `^(.*)\r(.*)`  worked. I was using actionscript, testing with this online tool: gskinner.com/RegExr